# Deleted /usr/share/backgrounds by mistake

Tags: desktop-background

I'm using standard Ubuntu 20.04

I have a folder of backgrounds (all public domain) that I use on my (necessary and unavoidable) Windows 10 partition, as a slideshow, for my desktop background.

I want to use the same backgrounds on my Ubuntu 20.04 partition, but I cannot find a way to keep the folder inside e.g. my Pictures folder, and then set them to rotate as a slideshow for my ubuntu background.

I got fed up and attempted to put them inside my /usr/share/backgrounds/ folder, and deleted the entire contents, replacing everything with just the images.

This was obviously a mistake, as now I cannot select anything in Backgrounds in the Settings app.

Could someone perhaps help me, either with a way to use the folder as a slideshow, or send me the contents of your /usr/share/backgrounds/ folder so that I can at least have the standard backgrounds back, or perhaps you have a third option?

Thanks kindly in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to simply use the power of APT to restore folder contents:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall \
$(dpkg -S /usr/share/backgrounds/ | sed "s/,//g" | sed "s|: /usr/share/backgrounds||")
```

Comment: Good one but wont work if he did what he said: " /usr/share/backgrounds/ folder, and deleted the entire contents" :)

Comment: The files are still listed/saved in dpkg database. Just tested the method - it works.

Comment: Thank you, N0rbert. That worked! Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: Looks more like the power of `dpkg`+`sed` than APT... Anyway, the two `sed` calls can be golfed into a single one: `sed -e "s@,\|: /usr/share/backgrounds@@g"`

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-wallpapers-focal
```

reinstalls the wallpapers from [focal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-wallpapers-focal). Change focal to another name for that release. Like so for 19:10:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-wallpapers-eoan
```

> Could someone perhaps help me, either with a way to use the folder as a slideshow

Easiest method: use a tool for it [Wallch](https://launchpad.net/wallpaper-changer) or [Slidewall](https://launchpad.net/slidewall) or [Drapes](https://store.kde.org/p/1129173/) (kde tool), or [Wallpaper-tray](https://www.pling.com/p/1129153/).